# Why can't I put exception handling logic in separate method without a return?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Scratch {

  public Scratch() {
    doStuff();
  }

  public String doStuff() {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(null);
        return "Integer: " + i;

      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          if (e.getMessage().equals("some message")) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("step 1");
          } else {
            throw new NumberFormatException("step 2");
          }
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Scratch();
  }
}
```

and I want to put the exception handling logic in its own method like this:

```
public class Scratch {

public Scratch() {
    doStuff();
}

public String doStuff() {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(null);
        return "Integer: " + i;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        handleException(e);
    }
}

private void handleException(NumberFormatException e) {
    if (e.getMessage().equals("some message")) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("step 1");
    } else {
        throw new NumberFormatException("step 2");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Scratch();
}
}
```

But I am getting a compiler error saying that the `doStuff` method is missing a return statement.

I don't understand why these seemingly equivalent implementations differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because the compiler can't figure that `handleException()` always throws an exception.  If it ever returned normally then the code would just keep executing, and reach the end of the method with no return statement.

In these situations it's convention to just throw an `AssertionError` with an appropriate message.

```
   public String doStuff() {
      try {
         int i = Integer.parseInt( null );
         return "Integer: " + i;
      } catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
         handleException( e );
         throw new AssertionError( "Should never get here.");
      }
   }
```

Comment: I prefer to make `handleException` return an `Exception`, and then in the catch just have `throw handleException(e);`. I find that my brain understands that faster than having to infer that `handleException` must be throwing an exception.

Comment: That's another idea, I think it would work well also.